# curl doesn't work during docker build

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, linux-mint

I am writing a Dockerfile based on wildfly image. I have isolated these lines where I am having some headache. The **curl** command doesn't work during build process. I have already uninstalled and installed Docker again but the error persists. My system is a Linux Mint.
In addition I tried to build that same Dockerfile in a RHEL and it worked like a charm.

**Here's the Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jboss/wildfly

RUN cd $HOME \
    && curl -O "http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar"
```

**Here's the error output:**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   1.03MB
Step 1/6 : FROM jboss/wildfly
 ---> b695bdcce374
Step 2/6 : RUN cd $HOME     && curl -O "http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar"
 ---> Running in 4fdcef7dbda1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:39 --:--:--     0
  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: central.maven.org; Unknown error
The command '/bin/sh -c cd $HOME     && curl -O "http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar"' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name resolution failing during docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786057/name-resolution-failing-during-docker-build)

Answer (score 2):

I could workaround the problem doing something like this:

```
docker build --add-host central.maven.org:151.101.56.209 .
```

but I'm not happy with that. I would like to say Docker to use my DNS instead of set fixed IP. It would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a DNS problem resolving the hostname.  You could try running docker with the --dns option (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)

```
docker run --dns=8.8.8.8
```

which will set the container /etc/resolv.conf for you.

Comment: The question was about a DNS issue happening during the `docker build` stage, and not the `docker run` stage. To influence the DNS server used during build, the whole daemon must be set up to have a working DNS system. This will mean the host's /etc/resolv.conf should include the correct DNS server to be used by the whole system-- including containers (and build steps). If the system's /etc/resolv.conf is really not appropriate for the containers, then the whole daemon can be configured to use a different DNS server by setting that in /etc/docker/daemon.json.

Comment: Adding to the above, you create `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, with contents like `{"dns": ["8.8.8.8"]}`, then restart Docker (e.g. `sudo systemctl restart docker`).