# Name resolution failing during docker build

Tags: docker

I am experiencing an issue where I receive the following error when issuing the docker build command:-

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dl.yarnpkg.com
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Here is my Dockerbuild file

```
# Base image
FROM ruby:2.5.0

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.lisT
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs yarn
```

The commands complete successfully when run outside of docker.

In order to resolve the issues I have tried the following

1. Adding DNS servers to /etc/docker/daemon.json - same issue
2. Uncommenting the DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4" line in /etc/default/docker  - same issue
3. Replacing the DNS servers I use locally in /etc/resolv.conf - same issue.

I have tried DNS servers from Google and OpenDNS, as well as multiple ISPs depending on the location im running the command from

Laptop is running Ubuntu 16:04 with Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825 installed.

Using the following also fails

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
```

causing the following error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So I know this isnt just a problem iwth the dl.yarnpkg.com host.

Running the docker build command with the no-cache option makes no difference.

Comment: What happens if you run `nslookup dl.yarnpkg.com 8.8.8.8` on your docker host outside of a container?

Comment: Server:  8.8.8.8
    Address: 8.8.8.8#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name: dl.yarnpkg.com
    Address: 104.16.60.173
    Name: dl.yarnpkg.com
    Address: 104.16.63.173
    Name: dl.yarnpkg.com
    Address: 104.16.61.173
    Name: dl.yarnpkg.com
    Address: 104.16.62.173
    Name: dl.yarnpkg.com
    Address: 104.16.59.173

As i said i have tried different DNS providers, and the problem occurs with them all.

Comment: I have also tried disabling dnsmasq in the ubuntu dns settings....no luck,...

Comment: Did you reload the docker engine after changing the daemon.json? What happens if you run `docker run -it --rm alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `docker run -it --rm alpine nslookup dl.yarnpkg.com`?

Comment: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 208.67.222.222
search Home
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: Second command gives nslookup: can't resolve 'dl.yarnpkg.com': Try again

Answer (score 8):

I am using Docker with Ubuntu 16.04 and sometimes I have name resolution problems too.

The only thing that made it through was adding `--network=host` when building. I'm not really sure what's going on but it seems it needs this to use your computer name resolution capabilities. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem but in CentOS 8

Comment: `--network=host` solved it for me, but the problem just recently appeared, even after a Docker daemon restart.

Comment: You set the network every time you issue a docker run command. It's weird because I believe it should work OK with bridge networks.

Answer (score 1):

At times I had this problem I needed to restart the docker daemon.

I am working in a virtual machine and I basically never shut it down, but instead freeze it and work again later. I also have to switch networks on the host which affects the virtual machine as well.

It seems that this confuses the docker daemon from time to time and a restart is necessary to get its network stack back into a consistent state.